# Variável global dentro de require node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function album(music){
            var album;
            request('http://localhost/socket/source.php?music='+music+'', function (error, response, result){
                data = JSON.parse(result);
                album = data['return'];
            });

            return album;
        }
```

Gostaria de ao chamar essa função retornasse o valor de album.

Estou tentando chamar a função assim:

```
io.emit('updateNext', {
                    'nextArtist': result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0]['Artist'], 
                    'nextMusic': result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0]['Title'],
                    'nextAlbum': album('eae')
                });
```

Porém está retornando indefinido. Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua função `album` realiza uma requisição, que por sua vez é assíncrona, portanto você deverá trabalhar com `promise` ou `callback`. Para utilizar `promise` você pode realizar a seguinte alteração na função:

```
function album(music) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request('http://localhost/socket/source.php?music=' + music, function (error, response, result) {
      data = JSON.parse(result);
      resolve(data['return']);
    });
  });
}
```

E a chamada:

```
album('eae').then(function (resultado) {
  io.emit('updateNext', {
    'nextArtist': result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0]['Artist'], 
    'nextMusic': result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0]['Title'],
    'nextAlbum': resultado
  });
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo. Me ajudou muito!

Comment: @PauloSérgioFilho se a resposta resolveu seu problema não esqueça de aceitá-la como correta clicando no botão de aceitar ao lado da resposta

Comment: Só estou aguardando o tempo necessário pra aceitar. Não pode ser de imediato :s